# Applying second-order differential operator vs applying first-order differential operator twice?

Tags: heat-equation, runge-kutta-methods

I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623972/heat-equation-calculation-gets-unstable-for-different-differentiation-matrices on stackoverflow concerning the calculation of a 1-dimensional heat equation:
$$\partial_t u=\partial_x^2u$$
I wanted to compare the different approaches
$$\partial_tu=\partial_x^2u$$
and 
$$\partial_tu=\partial_x\left(\partial_xu\right)$$
Both approaches should be solved using the RK4-method. Now I noticed that, while the first approach gives me the correct solution, the second one does not, it rather fluctuates strongly at the borders (for images refer to the question above). Thus I was wondering if both approaches are mathematically equal (they should, according to my understanding), or if there is a difference?

The used stencils (from the cited question):
For the second-order derivation operator I am using the central difference method from $x_{-2}$ to $x_{2}$, resulting in the equation
$$\partial_x^2f(x)=\frac{-f_{-2}+16f_{-1}-30f_0+16f_1-f_2}{12h^2}$$
and forward- respective backwards differentiation at the boundaries.

For the first-order derivation operator I used the same range, resulting in
$$\partial_xf(x)=\frac{f_{-2}-8f_{-1}+8f_1-f_2}{12h}$$
and also forward- respective backwards differentiation at the boundaries.

Comment: It is unclear what stencils you are using from the question.

Comment: I added the main stencils, should I also add the boundary stencils?

Comment: It really has nothing to do with the composition of the real operators. It is just two stencils which are both consistent with the second derivative, and one has numerically bad properties. Look up terms such as numerical dispersion. (Also I assume the second one should have $h^2$ in the denominator...)

Comment: @Ian: No, the second stencil is for the first order, thus the $\partial_x^2$ was wrong. Nevertheless, if I understand you correctly, you would suggest to use a larger stencil to counter the problem, or is it impossible to counter that problem?

Comment: So, a solution is to use a lower order stencil for the first order instead?

Comment: Most likely the problem is that one of these schemes is just unstable. High order schemes in space are often unstable if the time stepping is explicit.

Comment: Reducing the scheme to a simpler one is more stable, interesting, thanks!